# Paypal Live API Problem Thailand For Payment

Tags: api, paypal, sandbox, live

I have integrated the paypal payment system on my website. When I get the application from the sandbox, I cannot pay. On my website in Thailand, it gives an error when I pass the payment.Sms comes for confirmation. I can't fix the error that the bank didn't approve the card. SMS comes to $ 0.00.

Error Images ;

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9uJx.png)

http://prntscr.com/rqe1dy

Please help